# Prestashop Payment Module - doesn't appear in the back-office payment page

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I'm developing a payment module for PrestaShop, It appears successfully in the modules list page of the back-office/administration console. However, It doesn't appear in the payment modules page .

I set the tab variable :

```
$this->tab = 'payment_gateways';
```

and in the config.xml file :

```
    <tab><![CDATA[payment_gateways]]></tab>
```

please advice, How to make my module appears in the payment modules list in the back-office

Thanks

Comment: Did you extend the `PaymentModule` class: `class MyPaymentModule extends PaymentModule`?

Comment: Yes, I did, However, the issue persist !